# Angular 7 CLI installation Issue

Tags: node.js, angular, npm, angular7

Am trying to install Angular CLI 7.1.4 in windows 10.

> npm install -g @angular/cli@7.1.4

But am getting below error

> npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.2.2 (node_modules@angular\cli\node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
>
> npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.11: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
>
> npm ERR! code ERR_INVALID_OPT_VALUE
>   npm ERR! The value "false" is invalid for option "readableHighWaterMark"
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:

Please help me to fix this issue.

Node Version:

> v10.16.3

NPM Version:

> 6.9.0

Comment: please add the command you're trying to run

Comment: Am trying this command `npm install -g @angular/cli@7.1.4`

Comment: there's a fix mentioned [here](https://npm.community/t/npm-install-g-typescript-fails-with-npm-err-the-value-false-is-invalid-for-option-readablehighwatermark/8668/3)